# unity выдаёт ошибку invaild token = '='

Tags: unity3d

```
using UnityEngine;

public class playerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody rb;

    public runSpeed = 500f;
    public float strafeSpeed = 500f;
    public float jumpFroce = 15f;
    
    public bool strafeLeft = false;
    public bool strafeRight = false;
    public bool doJump = false;
    
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Правильно выдаёт.

```
public runSpeed = 500f;
```

какой тип у переменной?

---

Научитесь анализировать ошибки. В первую очередь сообщение указывает на линию, где есть ошибка, или рядом с ней.

Answer (score 0):

```
public runSpeed = 500f;
```

не указан тип у переменной runSpeed